# Why am I getting an error code when I run this code?

Tags: python

Why am I getting the following error code when I run this code:

> builtins.NameError: name 'string' is not defined

```
def explore_string():
    get_input()
    explore_chars(string)
    sum_digits(string)

def explore_chars(string):
    print("Original: ",string)
    print("Length:   ",len(string),"chars")
    print("2nd char: ",string[1])
    print("2nd last: ",string[2])
    print("Switched: ",string[-3:]+string[3:-3]+string[0:3])

def sum_digits(string):
    dig_sum=0
    l=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
    for i in string:
        if i in l:
            dig_sum+=int(i)
    print("Digit sum: ",dig_sum)
    
def get_input():
    string=input("Enter 10 or more chars ending with a period: \n-> ")
    while(len(string)<10 or string[len(string)-1]!='.'):
        string=input("-> Error! Try again: ")
    return string 

explore_string()
```

Comment: Format your code correctly. The very first line is not formatted.

Comment: Please post a [mre], including the ***full*** error traceback

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `explore_string` like this:

```py
def explore_string(): 
    string = get_input()
    explore_chars(string)
    sum_digits(string)
```

The result value of `get_input()` should be stored in a variable `string`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[Imentu's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69703190/9726179) answer seems like the right solution. However, I want to add some minor tips that could help you to solve such problems by yourself. Because you might encounter them many more times in the future (at least I did).

The error code oftentimes contains a lot of information about the problem that you're facing. In your case the `xxx is not defined` means that you are referencing an object `xxx` which Python doesn't know about yet (it is not defined).
Whenever you encounter this, then there are 2 main things you should check

- Did I forget to assign it? (which is the case here)
- Did I make a typo? (e.g. if you typed `strng = get_input()`)

If you combine this with the fact that the issue is centered around the word "string" and the approximate line number given by the error, then you should be able to find the issue.